# how to use jstl to iterate through four arraylists and create cells with each content

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am using the following code to create a table:

```
<c:forEach var="surveyName" items="${surveyList}"  varStatus="theCount"    >
    <tr>
    <td align="left"  style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;padding-left: 10px"  ><c:out value="${surveyName}"/> </td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

`surveyList` is the array I am passing to jsp. In the same way I have three more `arraylist`. I want each row to have four cells and each cells have content from the four arryalists i.e. first cell from first list second cell from second list and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is demonstration code.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fn" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%
    ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
    listA.add("a1");
    listA.add("a2");
    listA.add("a3");
    listA.add("a4");
    listA.add("a5");
    pageContext.setAttribute("listA", listA);
    ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    listB.add("b1");
    listB.add("b2");
    listB.add("b3");
    listB.add("b4");
    listB.add("b5");
    pageContext.setAttribute("listB", listB);
    ArrayList<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();
    listC.add("c1");
    listC.add("c2");
    listC.add("c3");
    listC.add("c4");
    listC.add("c5");
    pageContext.setAttribute("listC", listC);
    ArrayList<String> listD = new ArrayList<String>();
    listD.add("d1");
    listD.add("d2");
    listD.add("d3");
    listD.add("d4");
    listD.add("d5");
    pageContext.setAttribute("listD", listD);
%>
    <c:set value="${fn:length(listA)}" var="listSize" />
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <c:forEach begin="0" end="${listSize - 1}" var="current">
                <tr>                
                    <td>${listA[current]}</td>   
                    <td>${listB[current]}</td> 
                    <td>${listC[current]}</td> 
                    <td>${listD[current]}</td>                      
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body> 
</html>
```